# How to notify original case owner (user) when assigned via assignment rule during case creation?

Tags: assignment-rules, notification

How to notify original case owner (user) when assigned via assignment rule during case creation?

I need out-of-the-box solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

[image]

**Assigning an email template while drafting the rule steps by default makes the email option ticked .**